# E2E test suite get stuck when logging in to a google account

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, angular5, google-account

In my Angular5 app, I have an E2E test suite running on protractor that includes logging in to a google account. Recently, after the password has been entered, Chrome is being redirected to `https://accounts.google.de/accounts/SetSID` displaying a blank screen and nothing else happens. Eventually, the suite runs into a timeout.

When I enter the username and password manually (outside of the E2E environment), the browser also gets redirected to this URL for a second, but then promptly navigates to `https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/consent` where I get to allow or decline access to my account.

It looks like I need to fix some Chrome settings for the E2E environment, but which ones and how?

**Edit:** The page itself is blank, but the HTML body contains a single script tag:

```
<script nonce>
  location.replace('https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/signin\/oauth\/consent?authuser\x3d0\x26part\x3dAJi8hAMUl_5gA4GrIozXAyYpERMmUqdSAaQS-oLzjkegEK6wmwghwqKNYFd8jKuz3WjirmqMLgnvk9FNR-hVvO0bnWthA-dCrOVWyLKXl_GYL_xVerzhfMSNGPn7wziNYoQ5nKVyaWtH67YUR-O7gwmSW0dukrSjIUpg954e1KcAiMfrCf4dKRBFd8ENTdy4U5KHphQjWKPKnqsXf0hCUob6DFaLiiyUrDq9BaBkOFdnafHz0hP99JFGDa1Anul9oWYonB8ce4z485rPHpuGYBVmioRauqBXWQ1q62oNgDuo8qhFDsGUyxUyywgKQ-veZO05WHJcmmtbL_q0bmrPHD3yNl91vwl0uiF5NdRS_kZ6oKY_bxD562yawqNQdZ1nVfAGWmaYXyXjFd6EX0He351ugpyyezOZ0zBb-5BKv7IXWu2DiD3bd_E\x26as\x3dOnTvuJ0NpqEd3bqD8MVs-g\x26auth\x3dAwanw8ZCzvMxUzucWfpIL9mB__vh3DFsXzQGdSuyMdWciXu7MY6ww1lukyPl3EJ0B4FX5A.#');
</script>
```

Comment: We observe the same problem. 

However, when trying it out manually we don't get redirected to the consent page. But when we are manually going to the google sign on page, we get redirected to the "Choose an account from ***.com" page. 

This doesn't happen with our E2E test, which after uname+password ends up in the redirect page mentioned over.

Comment: In the redirect page there is a url that, if followed, will bring you to the page you are going to. We could extract this url from the redirect page and follow it, but we fear that our customers would also experience this ...behaviour. And they would NOT be able to performe the extraction :-)

Comment: @TorThorbergsen there is no link on that page, it is blank. It only contains a script tag in the body (cf. my edit).

Comment: Yes Anton, that is what I meant :-)
If you follow the url in that script you'll end up in the correct place.

Comment: @TorThorbergsen thanks, but is there a way to program the spec to follow the link?

Comment: Yes, that cannot be too hard to extract from the page, but you cannot expect your users to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually possible to extract the callback URL from the script, but it requires some meddling since the url string escapes special characters:

```
const returnScript = element(by.xpath('//body/script'));
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(returnScript), 10000)
 .then(() => {
   returnScript.getAttribute('innerHTML')
    .then(text => {
      let callbackUrl = text
        .match(/\'.*\'/)[0]
        .slice(1, -1);
      callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace(/\\\//g, '/');
      callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace(/\\x3d/g, '=');
      callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace(/\\x26/g, '&');
      // This was necessary for some reason, I assume you need to replace .de with your country domain
      callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace(/.com/, '.de');
      console.log(callbackUrl);

      browser.driver.get(callbackUrl);
    })
})
```

**Edit:** When I launched the same suite yesterday, the problem was simply gone. The above code was not necessary.

Comment: Awesome! But is this a problem only the E2E test encounters, or will our users too see this empty page?

Comment: One question: what is the "ec" you reference in the second line?